# d3.js How to create one paragraph element for sum of all json object values

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I have this d3 function which is trying to do the following tasks:

1. Read from json file
2. Get the sum of all "Count" values
3. Return one paragraph element that says "Total of (sum(Count)) orders from this range"

The issue I am having is that it's creating multiple paragraph elements for each object I have in the data. For example the data has total of 4 objects, therefore it returns 4 paragraph statements. How can I optimize this to return only one p element no matter how many objects are in the data, or is there a better way that I can accomplish the tasks listed above?

Data:

```
[{
 "Cars": "Toyota",
 "Count": 50000
},
{
 "Cars": "Honda",
 "Count": 40000
},
{
 "Cars": "Mercedes",
 "Count": 20000
},
{
 "Cars": "Jeep",
 "Count": 2200
}]
```

D3 Script

```
d3.json('orderQuantities.json', function(data) {    
            Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
                var sum = 0
                for ( var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
                    sum += this[i][prop]
                }
                return sum
            } 
            console.log(data.sum("Count"))
d3.select('body')                                            
.selectAll('p')                                            
.data(data)                                                 
.enter()                                                 
.append('p')                                             
.text(function(d) {
  return 'Total of ' + data.sum("Count")  + ' orders from this time range.';    
});});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use [Array - reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum `Count`, instead of creating a `sum` function; replacing `data.sum("Count")` to `data.reduce(function(acc, curItem) { return acc + curItem.Count }, 0)` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a few things in your script for it to work.

1. You don't need to do `selectAll('p')` since you're not updating any exisiting `p` elements. Instead you want to append a new one with your text/data.
2. You can also remove `.data(data).enter()` since that will append elements based on your data and we don't want that. We only want one `p` element instead of four.

The snippet below should do the job:

```
    d3.select('body')
     .append('p')
     .text(function(d) {
         return 'Total of ' + data.sum("Count") + ' orders from this time range.';
      });
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/e19b444x/

Comment: Hey thanks! this works very well. Would you be able to assist on this related D3 request? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43642014/5573429