# d3 ordering column rule based on JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this d3 function that generates a table based on my data's JSON output

```
function tabulate(data, columns) {
$("body").css("padding-top", "10px")
var table = d3.select('#response').append('table').attr('class', 'table table-bordered table-hover')
var thead = table.append('thead')
var tbody = table.append('tbody');

thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns).enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function(column) {
        return column;
    });

var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('tr');
console.log("rows: " + rows)
var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function(row) {
        return columns.map(function(column) {
            return {
                column : column,
                value : row[column]
            };
        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append('td')
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });
return table;
}
```

The data response varies based on input but one common field in the output is 'Count' I want this field to always be appended last on the table. Currently it displays on the table based on the order it's from the data.

Example dataset:

```
data: [{"Cars":"Mercedes","Count":281,"Type":"Automatic"},
      {"Cars":"Toyota","Count":1929,"Type":"Manuel"}]
```

Is there some logic that I can add to 
1. receive the response
2. Always set 'Count' as the last column when appending table

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're passing an array `columns` to your `tabulate` function based on which you organize your data before populating your rows. Where are you getting this from?

Based on your comment, the values in the `columns` array are dynamic and can include anything. What we can do here is look for the `count` header, remove it and then add it to the end. This way, we have our headers the way we want it and the table is generated accordingly. Check the snippet below:

```js
var data = [{
  "Cars": "Mercedes",
  "Count": 281,
  "Type": "Automatic"
}, {
  "Cars": "Toyota",
  "Count": 1929,
  "Type": "Manuel"
}];

// case where count is in the middle
var columns = ["Cars", "Count", "Type"]; 

// some basic array manipulation to remove it from the middle and put it in the end
var position = columns.indexOf("Count");
if(position != -1) {columns.splice(position, 1);}
columns.push("Count");

function tabulate(data, columns) {
  //$("body").css("padding-top", "10px")
  var table = d3.select('#response').append('table').attr('class', 'table table-bordered table-hover')
  var thead = table.append('thead')
  var tbody = table.append('tbody');

  thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns).enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function(column) {
      return column;
    });

  var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('tr');
  console.log("rows: " + rows)
  var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function(row) {
      return columns.map(function(column) {
        return {
          column: column,
          value: row[column]
        };
      });
    })
    .enter()
    .append('td')
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
  return table;
}

tabulate(data, columns);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="response">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help! The data is coming from an API output based on a post request..therefore the array of columns are dynamic and can change per request... The array I provided is one example, however the column "Count" is consistent along with all possible columns so I was trying to see how I could handle keeping "Count" at the end of any set of array columns.

Comment: @DanielTesfaye Check my edit. Now it basically searches for `count` in the headers and then puts it in the end of the `columns` array so the table is generated accordingly.